# Get Current Target Data for Turn-Based RPG

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a turn based combat RPG, inspired by Divinity: Original Sin, D&D, and the like.  Currently, I have a `Game Object` that contains all my charatcers currently in the scene, and each of those characters are just a `GameObject` that has the model (just a cube for now..) and a Charcter Stats Component, which is just this script:

```
 public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour {

    public string characterName;
    public int health;
    public int strength;
    public int dexterity;
    public int intelligence;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        health = 100;
        strength = 10;
        dexterity = 10;
        intelligence = 10;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

On the actual model for the character (again, just a cube for now) I have this User Interaction Script:

```
public class UserInteraction : MonoBehaviour {

    CharacterStats currentCharacterStats { get; set; }
    GameObject currentTargetCharatcerStats;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        currentCharacterStats = this.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<CharacterStats>();
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<CharacterStats>());
        Debug.Log(currentCharacterStats.characterName + " Clicked");

        //assing global taget stats
        var currentTarget = GameObject.Find("CurrentTarget");
        var currentTargetStats = currentTarget.GetComponent<CharacterStats>();
        currentCharacterStats = currentTargetStats;

    }    
}
```

The goal of this script is to get the `Character Stats` for whatever character I just clicked on and assign it to another GameObject called `CurrentTarget`, which only contains CharacterStats, which would be a sort of global value for other systems in the game will use.

The goal here is to allow the user to click on a target and get their health data to appear in a canvas that I have attached to my main camera and show the health value of the CurrentTarget however, I am not sure how to check if the currentTarget has changed in order to update the HUD's Health Value.  Am I storing this data incorrectly?

This is the script that I am currently using on my Text Component of my Canvas GameObject:

```
public class CurrentTarget : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterStats currentTarget;
    public Text healthText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        healthText = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        var target = GameObject.Find("CurrentTarget");
        var currentTargetStats = target.GetComponent<CharacterStats>();
        if (currentTargetStats != null)
        {
            currentTarget = currentTargetStats;
            healthText.text = "Health: " + currentTarget.health;
        }
    }
}
```

I hear getting a GameObject on Update is a very costly call, so I want to try to figure this out before more systems are added to the game. Thanks! Below is the current structure of my Scene:

[image: Current structure of my Scene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is not a good idea to do what you are doing in the `Update` method.
One solution could be to make your `CurrentTarget` class a singleton.

```
public class CurrentTarget : MonoBehaviour {

    static public CurrentTarget instance;
    // ...

    void Awake() {
        instance = this;
    }
```

This way, in your call to `OnMouseDown` you could do the following:

```
CurrentTarget.instance.updateTarget(currentTargetStats);
```

Then you would only need to create the `updateTarget` method which would take a `CharacterStats` object as a parameter and would do the required changes to the user interface (such as `healthText.text = "Health: " + currentTarget.health;`, etc.).

Comment: That's a great solution, thank you!  I'll give that a shot.  Silly of me not to think of that first..